# Why is Instabot going to sleep? ERROR - Request returns 429 error

Tags: python, api, runtime-error, instagram-api

I have this script that runs perfectly in my Jupyter notebook (Win 11 if that matters). But i sent it to my friend to run (Mac OS) and he's getting an error.

`ERROR - Request returns 429 error! WARNING - That means 'too many requests'. I'll go to sleep for 5 minutes.`

I uploaded the code into a Googel Colab notebook and tried running it from there and also started getting the error. But switching back to Jupyter and it runs again.
Why it be like that?
Any thoughts on how to fix it?

```
import os, shutil
from instabot import Bot
from google.colab import files

username = "username"
password = files.upload()
password = list(password.values())[0].decode("utf-8")

send_to = "another_username"

bot = Bot()

try:
    bot.login(username=username, password=password);
    bot.send_message("message", [send_to]);
except:
    pass

os.chdir(os.getcwd())

for folder in ['config/log', 'config']:
    for filename in os.listdir(folder):
        file_path = os.path.join(folder, filename)
        try:
            if os.path.isfile(file_path) or os.path.islink(file_path):
                os.unlink(file_path)
            elif os.path.isdir(file_path):
                shutil.rmtree(file_path)
        except Exception as e:
            pass
```

error

```
2022-12-01 05:24:48,332 - INFO - Instabot version: 0.117.0 Started
2022-12-01 05:24:48,332 - INFO - Instabot version: 0.117.0 Started
2022-12-01 05:24:48,332 - INFO - Instabot version: 0.117.0 Started
2022-12-01 05:24:48,332 - INFO - Instabot version: 0.117.0 Started
INFO:instabot version: 0.117.0:Instabot version: 0.117.0 Started
DEBUG:instabot version: 0.117.0:Bot imported from /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/instabot/bot/bot.py
2022-12-01 05:24:48,346 - INFO - Not yet logged in starting: PRE-LOGIN FLOW!
2022-12-01 05:24:48,346 - INFO - Not yet logged in starting: PRE-LOGIN FLOW!
2022-12-01 05:24:48,346 - INFO - Not yet logged in starting: PRE-LOGIN FLOW!
2022-12-01 05:24:48,346 - INFO - Not yet logged in starting: PRE-LOGIN FLOW!
INFO:instabot version: 0.117.0:Not yet logged in starting: PRE-LOGIN FLOW!
DEBUG:instabot version: 0.117.0:POST to endpoint: accounts/get_prefill_candidates/ returned response: <Response [429]>
DEBUG:instabot version: 0.117.0:Responsecode indicates error; response content: b'{"message":"Please wait a few minutes before you try again.","status":"fail"}'
2022-12-01 05:24:48,437 - ERROR - Request returns 429 error!
2022-12-01 05:24:48,437 - ERROR - Request returns 429 error!
2022-12-01 05:24:48,437 - ERROR - Request returns 429 error!
2022-12-01 05:24:48,437 - ERROR - Request returns 429 error!
ERROR:instabot version: 0.117.0:Request returns 429 error!
2022-12-01 05:24:48,444 - WARNING - That means 'too many requests'. I'll go to sleep for 5 minutes.
2022-12-01 05:24:48,444 - WARNING - That means 'too many requests'. I'll go to sleep for 5 minutes.
2022-12-01 05:24:48,444 - WARNING - That means 'too many requests'. I'll go to sleep for 5 minutes.
2022-12-01 05:24:48,444 - WARNING - That means 'too many requests'. I'll go to sleep for 5 minutes.
WARNING:instabot version: 0.117.0:That means 'too many requests'. I'll go to sleep for 5 minutes.
```

Comment: As it is posted your code does not do a single request to the API. The two lines that look like they would are skipped because they would raise an exception. Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @KlausD what do you mean? They won't raise an exception if you provide your Instagram username and password. I'm not putting my credentials here >.> ... And you can change send_to to artifyplz for practice.

Comment: `bot` is not even defined. Also, provide the full error traceback.

Comment: @KlausD ohdang, sorry, missed one line >.< ...

Comment: is it possible you whitelisted your jupyter notebook or something? maybe some permission issue, need to allow the bot to post to the api?

Comment: @Matthias interesting... Do you know how I could check that by any chance?

Comment: no, depends on the api. For example github api requires you to send some header with your username

Comment: @Matthias oh, I don't have any other code in the notebook. That's literally all of it and for some reason works in Jupyter on my win machine but not in Colab or my friend's Mac. I thought you meant that maybe my computer has some special permissions when running Jupyter.

Comment: no the error is saying you are querying their api too fast

Comment: @Matthias right, that doesn't make sense tho cuz it's only sending one request. And again, if i send the request or multiple requests from Jupyter they come through no problem

Comment: maybe something else is wrong, try to find out what is different between Jupyter and the rest. Password, environment, python version, etc. could be anything

Comment: @Matthias same password since the script is the same. Updated Colab to use the same Python version 3.6.7. Still getting the error.